# Distributing expectation over a quadratic function

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, random-variables, expectation

I saw this proof in [MIT Probability Courseware](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-05-introduction-to-probability-and-statistics-spring-2014/readings/MIT18_05S14_Reading5a.pdf) :

[image]

I understand the linearity of expectation and went through the proof of it as well. But how is the Expectation distributed over a quadratic function here in the second step of the proof ?

---

To clarify, I want to understand what allows us to distribute

\begin{align}E(X^2 + a)&=E(X^2) + E(a)\end{align}

This is not linear in X, so linearity of expectation shouldn't hold ?!

---

Further clarification :

I am also told [in the course](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2010/video-lectures/lecture-5-discrete-variables-probability-expectations/MIT6_041F10_L05.pdf) (Slide 2), to not assume :

E[g(X)] = g(E[X]) to be true in general.

If I could do change of variables like suggested by some answers, the above can always be made to be true ?

Answer (score 1):

I think your question has to do with this step

$$E((X-\mu)^{2}) = E(X^{2} -2\mu X + \mu^{2}) $$
$$ = E(X^{2}) - 2\mu E(X)  + \mu^{2}$$

$$E(X^{2} -2\mu X + \mu^{2}) =  E(X^{2}) -E(2\mu X) +E(\mu^{2})$$
$$ E(X^{2}) -2\mu E(X) + E(\mu^{2}) $$

you should note that $\mu = E(X)$ and is simply a constant so we can pull it out.

Then we have, if substitute 
$$E(X)^{2} -2 \mu \mu  + \mu^{2}  = E(X^{2}) - 2 \mu^{2}+ \mu^{2} = E(X^{2}) - \mu^{2}$$

It may also be useful to remember what the expectation is

For discrete variables it is

$$ E(X) = \sum_{i} x_{i} p(x_{i}) $$
for continuous random variables we have
$$ E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x) dx $$

so your question is about linearity

$ \mu $ is a constant consider why this works with summations and integrals

Answer (score 0):

Remember for a constant, $E(kX)=kE(X)$, $-2\mu$ and $\mu^2$ ara constants.

\begin{align}E(X^2-2\mu X+\mu^2)&=E(X^2)-E(2\mu X)+E(\mu^2)\\&=E(X^2)-2\mu E( X)+\mu^2 E(1)\\&=E(X^2)-2\mu E( X)+\mu^2 \end{align}

Edit:

Let $Y=X^2$, then $Y$ is a random variable. hence the problem becomes $E(Y-2\mu X+\mu^2)$.

Edit $2$:

If you let $Y=g(X)$, $E(g(X))=E(Y)$, the $g$ doesn't get out from the expectation in general, in the context of $g(X)=X^2$, note that the quadratic stays inside the expectation term. In general $E(X^2) \ne E(X)^2$.

Comment: I want to understand what allows us to distribute over the square of X, linearity of expectation allows to distribute over only linear functions of X, right ?

Comment: Let $Y=X^2$, then $Y$ is a random variable. hence the problem becomes $E(Y-2\mu X+\mu^2)$. Page $6$, the point on linearity in the bottom table might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

The expected value of the sum of random variables is the sum of their expected values. This is true for *any* two random variables for which expected values exist, not just for a single variable and linear functions of itself.

That is, in general, if $Y$ and $Z$ are random variables
and if $E(Y)$ and $E(Z)$ both exist,
$$ E (Y + Z) = E(Y) + E(Z). $$

But if $X$ is a random variable, then  $Y = X^2$ is a random variable
and so is $Z = -2\mu X + \mu^2.$ 
Moreover, $Y + Z = X^2 - 2\mu X + \mu^2.$
Therefore
\begin{align}
E(X^2 - 2\mu X + \mu^2) &= E(Y + Z)\\
&= E(Y) + E(Z)\\
&= E(X^2) + E(- 2\mu X + \mu^2).
\end{align}

I think you can work out the rest of it.